# Opacity on scroll for everyscreeen

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to add opacity on  a specific section of a picture but i'm having issue on different screens i don't know how to make a equation to fit it on every screen

```
var fadeStart=jQuery(document).height()/2.4 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
    fadeUntil=fadeStart+((jQuery(document).height()/100)*7.8) // 200px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
    fading = jQuery('.spy-opacitydiv')
;

jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/( fadeUntil*2.5);
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

any of you please guide me

Comment: Why do you have randomly placed CSS within your JS?

Comment: its mistake sorry for that , any way sir do you know the solution

Comment: I also have an id where i want opacity to finish will you help me to how to finish opacity when scroll reach that id ?

Comment: Please add more code and make this a snippet. You need to **reproduce the issue** you're having here, then I can help.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You need to add code **here** so that future users will be able to learn from your problem in case your website ever changes / goes offline.

Comment: i'll try to create one

Comment: You should also tell us what screens it doesn't work on. Mobile devices less than 480px wide? Internet Explorer 9?

Comment: desktop devices

Comment: Then what devices _does_ it work on? Your question implies that it works on some screens but not every screen.

Comment: it works on my screen 1366x

Comment: headhuntingfactory.com this is the site where i add it on iceberg picture